# Can a 97 f150 4.6 motor be swapped onto 2001 f150 4.6 triton body

Tags: engine, ford, f-150, ignition-coil, part-interchange

Is the ignition coil connectors need to be changed to work .. the 97 motor has the electrical connectors on the motor and 2001 has the ones on the plugs ... Do I need to change them.. does it give off a different fireing order or something different with one being on  the plug and the ones that is on the motor ...if that makes any sense to anyone

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

I would suspect the engine long block would fit just fine (physically), but you'd need to change over the entire wiring harness, coils, manifolds, and all electronic bits/pieces. So physically it should fit. However, the biggest issue would be is the 97 4.6L mod motor puts out 220hp/280tq, while the 2001 was 231hp/293tq. Not only will the tune in the ECU be off, your HP/TQ will be down as well.